# Fast database as an alternative to PHP array

Tags: php, database, nosql, database-connection, key-value

I have an array containing my reference variables, and in my scripts I need to catch one variable or two. In the current system, I have to include the entire array (and its elements) to use one element. It seems that using a database is better for two reasons:

1. One record is read instead of the entire array
2. Variables can be easily edited

However, there is a major drawback for using database: **on every php run, we need to make a connection to the database.**

Since simple database systems like SQLite has no server, persistent_connection is not like advanced database servers like `mysql`.

In action,

```
$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db');
```

takes more time (and consumes more resources) than

```
include 'array.php';
```

Is there any solution for having a basic database system (with fast connection) to be a replacement to PHP array and `include` file?

In other words, I need a simple database system with fast connection comparable with `fopen`. However, even `CDB` which is incredibly fast, is not fast enough on initial connection.

Comment: Don't optimize anything that does not *need to* be [optimized](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Does the array inclusion notably slow down your script? If not, just leave it.

Comment: @fab speed is only one aspect. When saving array as a file, it is not easy to edit elements. It is better and safer to edit variable with a database system.

Comment: OK, that's a valid reason. Then again, use a database and if that does not *notably* slow down your script, you are set. If it does, you always have the option to create a cached file from database that looks exactly like your current `array.php`.

Comment: @fab I had this idea, but it is not safe (at least to me) to dynamically write php file. If, for any reason, write fails (incomplete), then the `include` of a corrupt file will result fatal error in the entire script.

Comment: Did you try a **memory table**?

Comment: @LuisSiquot It's my ultimate desire to use mysql for both purposes; but it is not wise to add another query for getting a variable. In addition, if not using `persistent` initiating a connection on pages with no other database retrieve, it is a useful overload.

Answer (score 4):

By including the static array file you are essentially doing what caching systems do when they pull a result from a database. You are loading a pre-digested result directly from disk.

All database connections have some overhead (certainly more than including a rendered file). You use a database when you need operational maintainability for your data, but this comes at the cost of application overhead.

If you are not worried about persistance of the data, you may want to look at using a caching system like APC, memcached or redis.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered caching the variables? You could use APC or Memcached for this purpose. They will both be faster than a database since the data is stored in the RAM, not on the disc.

It will still be slower than just including the array.

Comment: Caching is a good idea, but we still have no gain for editing variable. We need to edit the original array file for editing any element. With database, we can do this by a user interface.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. If you use a database, you need to execute a query to modify any data: `$pdo->query("UPDATE...");`. When caching, you do the same, but without having to write the query: `$memcached->set("key",$val)`. I'm not saying it's the best approach, but since you seem reluctant to use a flat file and a database is too slow for you, I figure it might be an interesting option to try out.